# Chart.js color change of the data points

Tags: javascript, html, css, graph, chart.js

I want to make the dots solid color instead of a border of the line color. How do I remove the border color from the data points and make it a solid color?

**Current Output:**

[image]

**What I want:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set **point** and **point border** to same color.

```
datasets: [
    {
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data: Utils.numbers(NUMBER_CFG),
      fill: false,
      borderColor: Utils.CHART_COLORS.red,
      backgroundColor: '#1F363D', # Here
      borderWidth: 1,
      pointRadius: 5,
      pointBorderColor: '#1F363D' #Here
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the color value for each data point an array.

```
data: {
        labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
```

[image]

codepen - https://codepen.io/non_tech_guy/pen/VwzwRrL

The only catch I can see is the first borderColor value controls the color of the line but it is a step closer.

Comment: I don't want them to be the same color. The line has to be one color and the dot has to be a different color. But when I set a color for the dots the line color covers the dot too. Any way to remove that?

Comment: I updated my answer and added an image to show you the dot and line. Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: It results in the line color as the same as the dot. Please check this screenshot with the code snippet. https://ibb.co/wsYk7cK

Comment: The solution provided by yousof worked for me. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I also had a look at yousof answer, nice solution!